# ActiveRecord Query: select record where has at least one in a has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say you have this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :question
end
```

How do I search for all the questions that have answers without getting duplicate questions?

Say a question has two answers, if you do this:

```
Question.joins(:answers)
```

because it is an inner join, you'll get the question multiple times.

Is there a way to do this through the query interface without having to do a raw sql distinct or unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use a counter cache column. This gives you a database column in `questions` which counts the number of answers attached to it. As a bonus, it's probably faster to run this query.

Here's a Railscasts video that describes how to create one: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Then your query becomes:

```
Question.where("answers_count > 0")
```

You could even be fancy and define this as a scope:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  scope :answered, where("answers_count > 0")
end
```

It seems like a simple solution, but simple is good.

Comment: That's an awesome and simple fix!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Question.joins(:answers).uniq
```